# How to convert data from dataGridView to a PDF file?

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, datagridview

I have this dataGridView which I would like to convert to a PDF file. How do I do it? I searched online and found some codes but it seems like the website I found missed out on a lot of things.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Reflection;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text;

private void btnExportPdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Creating iTextSharp Table from the DataTable data
    PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(dataGridView1.ColumnCount);
    pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3;
    pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 30;
    pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    pdfTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1;

    //Adding Header row
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText));
        cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(240, 240, 240);
        pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
    }

    //Adding DataRow
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            pdfTable.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString());
        }
    }

    //Exporting to PDF
    string folderPath = "C:\\PDFs\\";
    if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
    }
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(folderPath + "DataGridViewExport.pdf", FileMode.Create))
    {
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        stream.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Converted this:

```cs
    //Adding DataRow
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            pdfTable.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
    TO:
    //Adding DataRow


     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
     {
          foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
          {
               try
               {
                   pdfTable.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString());
               }
               catch { }
           }
     }
```

And in new version that I downloaded this must changed:

```
cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(240, 240, 240);
```

to:

```
cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(240, 240, 240);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   u button name btn_PDF_DOWNLOAD_Click(.)
       
        {
          if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
          {
              SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
              save.Filter = "PDF (*.pdf)|*.pdf";
              save.FileName = "Envanter.pdf";
              bool ErrorMessage = false;
              if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
              {
                  if (File.Exists(save.FileName))
                  {
                      try
                      {
                          File.Delete(save.FileName);
                      }
                      catch (Exception ex) 
                      {

                          ErrorMessage = true;
                          MessageBox.Show("Diskteki Veriler Yazılamıyor!"+ex.Message);
                      }
                  }
                  if (!ErrorMessage)
                  {
                      try
                      {
                          PdfPTable pTable = new PdfPTable(dataGridView1.Columns.Count);
                          pTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 2;
                          pTable.WidthPercentage = 100;
                          pTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

                          foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
                          {
                              PdfPCell pCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(col.HeaderText));
                              pTable.AddCell(pCell);
                          }
                          foreach (DataGridViewRow viewRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
                          {
                              foreach (DataGridViewCell dcell in viewRow.Cells)
                              {
                                  pTable.AddCell(dcell.Value.ToString());
                              }
                          }

                          using (FileStream fileStream=new FileStream(save.FileName,FileMode.Create))
                          {
                              Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4,12f,20f,20f,12f);
                              document.Open();
                              document.Add(pTable);
                              document.Close();
                              fileStream.Close();
                          }
                          MessageBox.Show("İşlem Başarıyla Gerçekleştirildi","Bilgi");

                      }
                      catch (Exception ex)
                      {

                          MessageBox.Show("Veri Dışa Aktarılırken Bir Hata Meydana Geldi!"+ex.Message);
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
          else
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Kayıt Bulunamadı.","Bilgi");

          }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).