Is there a way to make a incremental array in C#?
I am making a sales report on C# and Microsoft Access
This report gathers all product sent to other branches in a month and prints on a PDF using iText.
All the data I need fills a datagridview like this:



PRODUCT
MAY-01
MAY-02
.....




potatoes
1
2



soda
2
4



burger
3
6




I used an array to fill the data and the code "works" but the thing is that the datagridview has different number of columns depending which day the user is printing (1st week, middle of the month, etc) and that some days we don't send product to the other branches and I want to skip null columns.
Is there a way to feed the array the true number of columns that is on the datagridview or just get the exact info from the datagrid?
Here is the code i use to fill the PDF Report with the DataGridView
float[] colwidth = { 15f, 15f, 15f, 15f, 15f };
// Getting Rows & Columns Counts
int dgvrowcount = dgvReporte.Rows.Count;
int dgvcolumncount = dgvReporte.Columns.Count;

//Create Table
Table ReporteMensual = new Table(colwidth);
    ReporteMensual.SetWidth(iText.Layout.Properties.UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100));

//Crear header
for (int i = 0; i < dgvcolumncount; i++)
{
    Cell headerCells = new Cell()
        .SetBackgroundColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY)
.SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER);
    //headerCells.SetNextRenderer(new RoundedCornersCellRenderer(headerCells));
    var gteCell = headerCells.Add(new Paragraph(dgvReporte.Columns[i].HeaderText));
    ReporteMensual.AddHeaderCell(gteCell);
}

//Fill table
for (int i = 0; i < dgvrowcount; i++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < dgvcolumncount; c++)
    {
        Cell cells = new Cell()
            .SetBackgroundColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.ColorConstants.WHITE)
.SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER);

        var gteCell = cells.Add(new Paragraph(dgvReporte.Rows[i].Cells[dgvReporte.Columns[c].HeaderText].Value.ToString()));
        ReporteMensual.AddCell(gteCell);
    }
}

Everything works, but I need to see how to feed the array or is there another function?

Why is data arranged in a non-normalized structure? Is this how it is stored in Access? Normalize data then pivot with CROSSTAB.

Not clear to me what you need. Isn't your code already getting the DGV column count? And if array is used to fill DGV, what do you mean by "how to feed the array"? Haven't you already done that when filling DGV?

@June7
The data is stored in acces like this:
| DATE  |PRODUCT|QUANTITY|
And i call it with a pivot to get the date column.
I just need to print it on PDF using iText but i need to know how to print the datagridview directly because the number of columns changes depending of how many days the company made deliveries.

@June7 What i need know is if there is a way to feed this array depending of the number of columns float[] colwidth = { 15f, 15f, 15f, 15f, 15f }; because sometime the report show from 10, 15 or even the whole 30-31 days of the month.
Or is there any other way to print the datagridview directly into the iText PDF File

I am still confused. Exactly what is the process? 1) pull data from Access to DGV, 2) build array from DGV, 3) build iText from array? At what point do you need to know column count? How do you pull data from Access - open a recordset of the CROSSTAB query? Can get its column count. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45910612/how-to-convert-data-from-datagridview-to-a-pdf-file

@June7
I already have the data i want on the datagridview. i just need help or a tip/advice on how to empty the datagridview on an Itext report because in some situations the Datagridview sometimes has 3 columns and sometimes it has 10  columns.
Sorry if i cant explain very well, English in not my primary language

I gave you a link to a possible solution. Did you explore?
